# Global Variable - Oracle Form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am writing logic in custom.pll oracle forms. I want a global variable to capture value from one form and pass it to another form and execute the query. Below is the code

```
procedure event(event_name varchar2) is 
form_name varchar2(50):= name_in('system.current_form'); 
  block_name varchar2(50):= name_in('system.cursor_block');
   v_group_name varchar2(255);
   V_GROUP VARCHAR2(255);
  begin
     if (event_name = 'ZOOM') then   
      if (form_name = 'FNDSCRSP' and block_name = 'RESPONSIBILITY') then 
        v_group_name:=Name_in('REQUEST_GROUP_NAME');
         fnd_function.execute(FUNCTION_NAME=>'FND_FNDRSGRP',  
                             OPEN_FLAG=>'Y',  
                             SESSION_FLAG=>'Y'  

                           );
       IF(FORM_NAME='FNDRSGRP' AND BLOCK_NAME='GROUPS') THEN
        V_GROUP:=NAME_IN('REQUEST_GROUP_NAME');
        V_GROUP:=V_GROUP_NAME;
        EXECUTE_QUERY;
       END IF;
      END IF;
      END IF;
  end event;
```

Comment: try to relace `form_name` with `:global.form_name`, and `block_name` with `:global.block_name`, and use `Call_Form` routine.

Comment: Not working can you please tell me how to declare a global variable in custom.pll and assign item value to it